# Is there any way to align these values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a datatable with a column that contains values of type integer, but when i show those values on my view numbers arent aligned well, so i have a value in a row = 600 and in another row = 1200 and the 6 of 600 is aligned with the thousand digit (1) instead with the hundreeds.

[image]

And this is my view with my data table:

```
<table id="example1" class="table table-striped table-responsive" width="100%">
                        <thead class="thead">

                            

                            <tr>
                                <th style="display: none">Codigo</th>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>Producto</th>
                                <th>Tipo de Producto</th>
                                <th>Marca</th>
                                <th>Modelo</th>
                                <th>Moneda de Compra</th>                                                                       
                                <th class="quitarDecimales">Costo Total</th>
                                <th>Moneda de Venta</th>
                                <th class="quitarDecimales">Precio de Lista</th>
                                <th>Margen Bruto</th>
                                
                                <th style="width: 12%">Accion</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                           
                            @foreach($file as $key => $product)
                            @if($product->status == 1)
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="display: none">{{ $key+1 }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $product->id }}</td>
                                    <td>{{$product->marca->brandName . " " . $product->modelo->modelName}}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $product['ptype']['productType']}}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $product->marca->brandName }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $product->modelo->modelName}}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $product->coin }}</td>                                    
                                    <td>{{ $product->costUSD }}</td>
                                    <td>{{$product->sale_coin}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$product->list_priceUSD}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$product->marginUSD}}</td>
                                    
                                    @php
                                    $count_product = App\Model\Purchase::where('product_id',$product->id)->count();
                                    @endphp
                                        <td>


                                        <!--<a title="Download" id="download" class="btn btn-sm btn-success"
                                            href="/products/download/{{ $product->file }}"><i
                                                class="fa fa-download"></i></a>-->
                                        <a title="Edit" class="btn btn-sm text-white"
                                            style="background-image: linear-gradient(200deg, #070525ce 1%, rgb(1, 0, 5)100%);"
                                            href="{{ route('products.edit', $product->id) }}"><i
                                                class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
                                        <a title="Delete" id="delete" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"
                                            href="{{ route('products.delete', $product->id) }}"><i
                                                class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
                                        <a title="Info" id="info" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" href="{{route('products.detail', $product->id)}}" ><i class="fa fa-eye" ></i></a>
                                        
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            @endif

                                
                            @endforeach
                        </tbody>
                        
                    </table>
```

So i tried doing this:

```
    div tbody tr{
  text-align: center;
 }
```

Which aligns my number digits of the different rows in my table but my thead titles are not aligned. My values go too far to the right.

[image]

Comment: So you want text aligned from left?

Comment: Exactly  @ToklCz

Answer (score 1):

By default text is aligned to the left in tables which is what you are seeing above. If you want the numbers to be aligned correctly you need to add `text-align:right;` to the `td` elements which contain numbers.

It looks like you might be using BootStrap, in which case they already have a class you can use called `text-right` which will set the `text-align` to `right`.

If you are not using BootStrap you can add the class yourself like this:

```
<style>
    .text-right{
        text-align: right;
    }
</style>
```

then add the class to the `td` elements as needed.

Comment: This alignment is what im looking but the issue is that the values go too much to the right and now the thead titles are unaligned. I´ll edit the question.

Comment: @matuco1998 Based on your edit I would try only adding the text-align right to the cells which contain numbers, it looks like you're applying it to all cells. Another thing you could try if you do not want the numbers all the way to the right is to add `padding-right: 10px` to the number cells (in addition to the right text align) and play around with the amount of padding. That would force the data more to the left while keeping them all aligned.

Answer (score 0):

My stylesheet:

```css
div tbody tr .numero{
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 50px;
}
    
div tbody tr{
    text-align: center;
}
    
div thead tr{
     text-align: center;
}
```

My view:

```html
<table id="example1" class="table table-striped table-responsive" width="100%">
    <thead class="thead">
        <tr>
            <th style="display: none">Codigo</th>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Producto</th>
            <th>Tipo de Producto</th>
            <th>Marca</th>
            <th>Modelo</th>
            <th>Moneda de Compra</th>
            <th class="quitarDecimales">Costo Total</th>
            <th>Moneda de Venta</th>
            <th class="quitarDecimales">Precio de Lista</th>
            <th>Margen Bruto</th>
            <th style="width: 12%">Accion</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($file as $key => $product)
        @if($product->status == 1)
        <tr>
            <td style="display: none">{{ $key+1 }}</td>
            <td>{{ $product->id }}</td>
            <td>{{$product->marca->brandName . " " . $product->modelo->modelName}}</td>
            <td>{{ $product['ptype']['productType']}}</td>
            <td>{{ $product->marca->brandName }}</td>
            <td>{{ $product->modelo->modelName}}</td>
            <td >{{ $product->coin }}</td>
            <td class="numero">{{ $product->costUSD }}</td>
            <td>{{$product->sale_coin}}</td>
            <td class="numero">{{$product->list_priceUSD}}</td>
            <td class="numero">{{$product->marginUSD}}</td>
            @php
            $count_product = App\Model\Purchase::where('product_id',$product->id)->count();
            @endphp
            <td>
                <!--<a title="Download" id="download" class="btn btn-sm btn-success"
                    href="/products/download/{{ $product->file }}"><i
                        class="fa fa-download"></i></a>-->
                <a title="Edit" class="btn btn-sm text-white"
                    style="background-image: linear-gradient(200deg, #070525ce 1%, rgb(1, 0, 5)100%);"
                    href="{{ route('products.edit', $product->id) }}"><i
                    class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
                <a title="Delete" id="delete" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"
                    href="{{ route('products.delete', $product->id) }}"><i
                    class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
                <a title="Info" id="info" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" href="{{route('products.detail', $product->id)}}" ><i class="fa fa-eye" ></i></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        @endif
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```